# How to use .each in an ajax call

Tags: jquery

I get a console error that says: $.each(...).done is not a function, when running this code. The php code that it is posting to to insert records into the database is working as I can see the file names in the database. I just need to fix my loop to stop getting the error but not sure what is wrong here.

```
$("#edit_pic").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = $('input[name="file"]').val()
        var data = JSON.parse(files)
    }

    $.each(data, function (index, item) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/add-support-images.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                data: item.file_name
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#edit_pic").prop("disabled", true).html("Uploading...");
            },
        });
    })

    .done(function (data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            console.log(data.message);


        } else {

            console.log(data.message);

        }

    })
```

php:

```
$response = array();
            $id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `product_images` (`pic_name`,`product_id`) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $_POST['data'], $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();


        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "success";
```

Comment: `each` doesn't have a done method but the ajax function does. You may wish to visit the jquery documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `.done` to after `$.ajax`:

```
$("#edit_pic").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = $('input[name="file"]').val()
    var data = JSON.parse(files)
}

$.each(data, function (index, item) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/add-support-images.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            data: item.file_name
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#edit_pic").prop("disabled", true).html("Uploading...");
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            console.log(data.message);


        } else {

            console.log(data.message);

        }

    });
});
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, with the above code you would see the success message for each item, as they are sent individually. To have all items sent in **one** ajax call, you could do something like this:

```
let items = [];

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    items.push({data: item.file_name});
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'functions/add-support-images.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: items,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#edit_pic").prop("disabled", true).html("Uploading...");
    },
}).done(function (data) {
    if (!data.success) {
        console.log(data.message);
    } else {
        console.log(data.message);
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** This would likely require updating your PHP code to accept an array of items to insert, rather than a single item.

Comment: thank you. The error no longer displays. But my success message is showing up the same number of times as records inserted.

Comment: Yes, that's because you're make an ajax call for each record. An alternative would be to update your PHP code to accept an array of values to be updated. Then you could use `$.each` to just put each `item.file_name` value into an array. Then make the ajax call *outside* of `$.each`.

Comment: You've lost me a bit there. I have added the php to my original question.

Comment: How do I get "items" with the php?  `$_POST['items']` doesn't seem to pick it up.

Comment: @user8463989 That would involve changing your PHP, not something I haven't used that for awhile, so can't really help there. The reason you may need to change the PHP is because in the second example I gave, you are now passing in an array (`items`) rather than a single item. You would need to change the the PHP to do some sort of loop over `$_POST['items']` to insert the new records.